# Hypothesis Testing for the Binomial Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Consider the following problem:

> $H_0:p=0.2, H_1: p\neq 0.2$
>
> $X\sim B(25,0.2)$
>
> Find the critical region for a hypothesis test using a $5\%$ significance level.

I have found

$$\begin{aligned}
P(X=0)&=0.0038\\
P(X\leq1)&=0.0274\\
P(X\geq9)&=0.0468\\
P(X\geq10)&=0.0173\\
\end{aligned}$$

I therefore said that the critical region is $X=0$ and $X\geq10$, because we require the probability in each tail to be at most $0.025$.

However, the textbook answers say that the critical region is $X\leq1$ and $X\geq10$. They say that $1$ should be selected rather than $0$ because $0.0274$ is closer to $0.025$ than $0.0038$.

Which of these is correct? Or are they both correct?

Comment: I want to add to my answer below, that it's not an argument to answer the question, that $0.0274$ is closer to $0.025$ than $0.0038$. The only thing you have to respect is the fact, that the type 1 error must be smaller, equal or approximately to $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the definition of the rejection region. Here four possibilities:

The rejection region is given by $[0,c_1]\cup [c_2,25]$ such that

1. $P(X\leq c_1)\leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $P(X\geq c_2)\leq\frac{\alpha}{2}$
2. $P(X\leq c_1)+P(X\geq c_2)\leq \alpha$
3. $P(X\leq c_1)\approx \frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $P(X\geq c_2)\approx\frac{\alpha}{2}$
4. $P(X\leq c_1)+P(X\geq c_2)\approx \alpha$

You see, that definition 3 and 4 are a little bit more handwaving.

For definition 1, you have to take $c_1=0$ and $c_2=10$. But with definiton 2 you can choose $c_1=1$ and $c_2=10$.